# Can the pre-order bonus color crystals be traded? Can I get more?

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

I got the black/yellow color stone for pre-ordering The Old Republic, but I look a little unbalanced as a Jedi Sentinel with two lightsabers — the other is blue.  As such I was hoping I could convince someone to trade me theirs, but I don't know if this is possible due to the special nature of the item.  Can it be traded?

Comment: Oh, you want to know not if they can be traded, but if you can get more than one. Perhaps you should change the title to be more accurate?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can buy another color crystal on the Republic (or Imperial) fleet. Use your map, click the Vendors button to show vendors, and look for the Pre-order Crystal Vendor tucked in a corner along the outer circle.

Comment: Interesting. I assume the vendor is limited to pre-orderers?

Comment: Yes, much like the security key vendor is limited to those with a security key and the CE vendor is limited to CE purchasers.

Answer (score 4):

No, it can not be traded. It is bind on pickup (soulbound).

Comment: Dang. Guess I'll have to try to find one of the other black-core sabers.